# Issues with named pipes communication with c++ recieving c# message

Tags: c#, c++, named-pipes

The c# code sends the message correctly and has never given any issues. I have re-written my c++ DLL and now a new problem has occurred when it is receiving a message. If I was to send the message abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxw it will receive it like abcd then efghi etc. Sometimes adding unknown characters to the end of what it receives. This is bad as with the strings separated or being mixed my DLL doesn't understand. This has not always been an issue until I re-wrote the code. The only problem is as far as I'm aware I wrote it the same way so it shouldn't of changed. Here is the C++ Named pipe code. If you need the C# though you shouldn't I can put it in later. This is being made in Visual Studio 2019 edition.

```
//Information\\
//----------------------------------------\\

//File Name: Client.cpp
//Date Of Creation: 23/11/2019
//Purpose
/*
This file is to handle the interprocess communication
between this DLL and the UI written in C#.
*/

//----------------------------------------\\

//Internal Includes\\
//----------------------------------------\\

#include "Client.h"
#include "Console.h"

//----------------------------------------\\

//Global Variables\\
//----------------------------------------\\

HANDLE Client::hPipe1 = NULL;
HANDLE Client::hPipe2 = NULL;
BOOL Client::Finished = false;

//----------------------------------------\\

//Functions\\
//----------------------------------------\\

/*
Used to start the connection to the external UI.
*/
int Client::MakeConnection()
{
    Console::DebugOut("Client::MakeConnection() STARTING\n");
    try 
    {
        LPTSTR lpszPipename1 = (LPTSTR)"\\\\.\\pipe\\Omni";
        LPTSTR lpszPipename2 = (LPTSTR)"\\\\.\\pipe\\Omni2";
        while ((hPipe1 == NULL || hPipe1 == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) || (hPipe2 == NULL || hPipe2 == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)) {
            CloseHandle(hPipe1);
            CloseHandle(hPipe2);
            Sleep(500);
            hPipe1 = CreateFile(lpszPipename1, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
            hPipe2 = CreateFile(lpszPipename2, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
        }
        Console::DebugOut("Client::MakeConnection() OK\n");
    }
    catch (exception ex)
    {
        Console::DebugOut("Client::MakeConnection() FAILED\n");
        Console::DebugOut("Error: %s\n", ex.what());
    }
    return 1;
}

/*
This function will send information back to the external UI.
*/
int Client::SendInformation(string Information)
{
    Console::DebugOut("Client::SendInformation(%s) STARTING\n", Information.c_str());
    char buf[100];
    DWORD dwBytesToWrite = strlen(buf);
    DWORD cbWritten;
    try
    {
        std::ostringstream str_stream;
        str_stream << Information.c_str();
        std::string OutCome = str_stream.str();
        buf[OutCome.size()];
        buf[OutCome.size()] = OutCome[OutCome.size()];
        WriteFile(hPipe1, buf, dwBytesToWrite, &cbWritten, NULL);
        memset(buf, 0xCC, 100);
        Console::DebugOut("Client::SendInformation(%s) OK\n", Information.c_str());
    }
    catch (exception ex)
    {
        Console::DebugOut("Client::SendInformation(%s) FAILED\n", Information.c_str());
        Console::DebugOut("Error: %s\n", ex.what());
    }
    return 1;
}

/*
This function will loop until it recieves a transmission from the external UI.
*/
string Client::RecieveInformation()
{
    Console::DebugOut("Client::RecieveInformation() STARTING\n");
    BOOL fSuccess;
    char chBuf[100];
    DWORD dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD)strlen(chBuf);
    DWORD cbRead;
    int i;
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            fSuccess = ReadFile(hPipe2, chBuf, dwBytesToWrite, &cbRead, NULL);
            if (fSuccess)
            {
                string overall = "";
                stringstream ss;
                ss << chBuf;
                ss >> overall;
                overall.resize(cbRead);
                Console::DebugOut("Client Recieved: Bytes: %d String: %s\n", cbRead, overall.c_str());
                Console::DebugOut("Client::RecieveInformation() OK\n");
                return overall;
            }
            if (!fSuccess && GetLastError() != ERROR_MORE_DATA)
            {
                Console::DebugOut("Client::RecieveInformation() FAILED\n");
                Console::DebugOut("Error: Can't Read Pipe2\n");
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
                if (Finished) {
                    CloseHandle(hPipe1);
                    CloseHandle(hPipe2);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (exception ex)
    {
        Console::DebugOut("Client::RecieveInformation() FAILED\n");
        Console::DebugOut("Error: %s\n", ex.what());
    }
}

/*
Wait for a reply from the external UI.
*/
void Client::WaitForReply()
{
    Console::DebugOut("Client::WaitForReply() STARTING\n");
    try 
    {
        bool GotReply = false;
        BOOL fSuccess;
        char chBuf[100];
        DWORD dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD)strlen(chBuf);
        DWORD cbRead;
        while (!GotReply) {
            fSuccess = ReadFile(hPipe2, chBuf, dwBytesToWrite, &cbRead, NULL);
            if (chBuf != NULL && fSuccess) {
                std::ostringstream str_stream;
                str_stream << chBuf;
                std::string dong = str_stream.str();
                GotReply = true;
                Console::DebugOut("Client::WaitForReply() OK\n");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (exception ex)
    {
        Console::DebugOut("Client::WaitForReply() FAILED\n");
        Console::DebugOut("Error: %s\n", ex.what());
    }
}

//----------------------------------------\\
```

Comment: For sure, that line: `buf[OutCome.size()];` is useless

Comment: Aha yeah I've already changed that. Wasn't the function that isn't working though

Comment: The following 2 lines are also wrong: (1) `char buf[100];` (2) `DWORD dwBytesToWrite = strlen(buf);`. `buf` is uninitialized and thus its length is undefined. **And there are many more errors in that code**. When you rewrite code, you should write unit test and do only small changes at a time.

Comment: @Phil1970 Thanks to your help I have fixed my code.